# Code working on simulator not on phone

Tags: iphone, mobile, ios-simulator

I am working on mobile website.I was testing it on ios simulator.
The code works fine!!

Now i test the code on i-phone.
The code doesn't work!!!

I can't figure out any code errors!

What could be probable reasons for this?

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: A lot of things could be different, including specific OS version, speed of processor, or speed of data connection. Please post some code and error messages for us to specifically help.

Comment: "The code doesn't work" means nothing. We need to know in what way it doesn't work. Errors? Wrong results?

Comment: Don't forget that the simulator is NOT case sensitive, but the devices ARE.

Comment: could you tell exactly what happened when you try to run your build on device. Are you using ARC.

Answer (score 0):

Check your IOS versions, or images if any are using in app. simulator is case insensitive and device is sesnsitive. or post your part of code here.

Answer (score 0):

If you use plists in your code, double-check their filenames where you call them. The device is case sensitive, but the simulator is not.

Answer (score -1):

Check your provisioning profile and also try to quit the xcode and run the code in device.

Comment: A provisioning profile would prevent him from RUNNING the app. Not from having the code perform differently.